# How do I use LocalStorage values to save a specific background-color of a button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage, bootstrap-popover

What I am trying to do is to use the values that I sucessfully stored in the LocalStorage. Depending on which color that is selected, the value of that color will be saved in the LocalStorage (red, green or blue). My question is, how can I now use these values to save the background-color of these individual buttons for next time of use? Any help would be appreciated!

Link for running the code: `https://jsfiddle.net/Lzj3g86f/7/`

```js
// Creates a Popover
$("[data-toggle=popover]").popover({
    html: true,
    sanitize: false,
    trigger: 'focus',
    content: function(){
      return $('#popover-content').html();
    }
  });
// Target the Button That is Clicked
var targetBtn;
$('.myBtn').each((i, item) =>{
  $(item).click((e) =>{
    targetBtn = e.target;
  });
});
// Set the Color of the Buttons
function setColor(c){
  var i = $(targetBtn).index();
  $(targetBtn).css("background", saveColorPref(i, c));
}
// Creates Data items inside LocalStorage
var saveColorPref = (i, c) =>{
  localStorage.setItem("color-" + i, c);
  return c;
}
// Retrieves Data items From LocalStorage
var getColorPref = (i) =>{
  return localStorage.getItem("color-" + i) || "";
}
/*
  Now i want to make use of the Stored Values so that the picked colors
  for the buttons will be saved for next time. I understand how to store text in the LocalStorage,
  but how can I now use these values to save the background-color of these individual buttons?
*/
```

```css
    .popover-content{
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-around;
      align-items: center;
      background: #efefef;
      width: 230px;
      height: 80px;
    }
    .close{
      color: #aaaaaa;
      float: right;
      font-size: 28px;
      font-weight: bold;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0px;
      left: 210px;
    }
    .close:hover,
    .close:focus{
      color: #000;
      text-decoration: none;
      cursor: pointer;
      transition: 0.5s;
    }
    .myBtn{
      background-color: #DCDCDC;
      border: 0.5px solid #808080;
      color: white;
      width: 30px;
      height: 30px;
      border-radius: 6%;
      text-align: center;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: inline-block;
      font-size: 16px;
    }
    .demo1,.demo2,.demo3{
      border: none;
      color: white;
      width: 60px;
      height: 60px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      text-align: center;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: inline-block;
      font-size: 16px;
    }
    .demo1{
      background-color: red;
    }
    .demo2{
      background-color: green;
    }
    .demo3{
      background-color: blue;
    }
    .hide{
      display: none;
    }
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <body>
    <button class="myBtn" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-html="true">1</button>
    <button class="myBtn" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-html="true">2</button>
    <div id="popover-content" class="hide">
      <button class="demo1" onClick="setColor('red')">Red</button>
      <button class="demo2" onClick="setColor('green')">Green</button>
      <button class="demo3" onClick="setColor('blue')">Blue</button>
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
    </div>
  </body>
</body>
```

Comment: How do you "identify" each button? Index is not a good way of remembering your buttons. It makes your code hard to maintain. If you could set IDs or unique class-names or names, this is much achievable. Now you can store the "identifier" and "color-preference" in local storage and retrieve it during load.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to store a background color with the item, you're going to need to store the item as an object instead of just the name.

I recommend adding logic like this to your add method:

```
function add() {
    var task = document.getElementById('task').value;
    var todos = get_todos();
    var newTask = {
                name:task, 
                id: "item" + todos.length, 
                priority: {
                            isPriority:false, 
                            color:""
                          }
             };

    todos.push(newTask);
    localStorage.setItem('todo', JSON.stringify(todos));

    show();

    return false;
}
```

Then, when you show() those, your loop will look like this:

```
  for (var i = 0; i < todos.length; i++) {
      var todo = todos[i];
      html += "<p id='item" + i + "' isPriority='" + 
      todo.priority.isPriority + "'>" + todo["name"] + '<p>' + 
      "<button class='remove'>Delete</button>" + " " + 
      "<button class='priority' value='item" + i + "'>Priority</button>";
  };
```

Then when you set the priority on the object, you're just setting the

```
todos[i].priority.isPriority = true;
```

and

```
todos[i].priority.color = "red";
```

If you want to define your color based on the property, you could just set a property in the html as isPriority=true and then in css do this:

```
[isPriority="true"] {
    background-color: red;
}
```